# Validando formato CSV em Ruby

Tags: ruby

Estou precisando validar o formato do arquivo CSV em Ruby puro, a validação é para o header. Criei este código, mas não está funcionando. O que estou fazendo de errado? Sou novato em Ruby.

```
require 'csv'
csv_file= CSV.read('Relatorio_de_Campanhas.csv')

expected_header = ["Campanha", "Visualizações"]
$csv_error = true if expected_header && csv_file

def check_header(expected_header,csv_file)
  header = CSV.open(csv_file, 'r') { |csv| csv.first }
  valid_csv = true
  (0..header.size - 1).each { |i|
    if header[i] != expected_header[i]
      valid_csv = false
    end
  }

  if !valid_csv
    $csv_error = "
    Header:
     #{header}
    Expected Header:
     #{expected_header} "
  end
  valid_csv
end

check_header(expected_header, csv_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

O método [`open`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) em `CSV` espera receber o nome de um arquivo como o primeiro parâmetro, mas você está a passar o conteúdo retornado pelo `CSV.read('Relatorio_de_Campanhas.csv')`, que não é o nome do arquivo.

Ao trocar `CSV.open(csv_file, 'r')` por `CSV.open("Relatorio_de_Campanhas.csv", 'r')`, o código pode ser executado sem erros.